# Matplotlib Quiver memory leak

Tags: python, qt, memory-leaks, matplotlib

I have created quite a nice visualization program using Qt as the interface layer and matplotlib to draw much of the content.  I use contour and countourf as well as text and lines and never run into problems with releasing objects.

As soon as I start calling Axes.quiver I get leaks.  With the size of the dataset it adds up quickly.  The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import ma
import time

X,Y = meshgrid( arange(0,2*pi,.04),arange(0,2*pi,.04) )
U = cos(X)
V = sin(Y)

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
for i in range(90):
    Q = ax.quiver( U, V)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    Q.remove()
```

I know this simple snippet isnt drawing to screen (leak becomes worse then).

Q has a sys.getrefcount of 4 so nothing I am able to do seems to get rid of it.  Calls to fig and ax clear only reduce the refcount to 2.  Quiver draws the image i want, but I am completely out of ideas.

My code is much more complex than this.  I have tried completely replacing the axes objects but that doesnt help.  I really am not free to replace the Figure instance.

Comment: suspect this is a bug in the container class related to circular references and missing cleaning one of them up when calling `remove`.  You should probably create an issue on github for this.

Comment: also, if you are embedding don't import `pyplot` (but thank you for a non-embedded example of the problem)

Comment: I only included the Pyplot for a minimal example

Comment: I posted it to maplotlib github and it was confirmed by a dev as a bug.  Don't know if or when it will receive attention.  For now I am using a (horrible) work around.  For my program I have an immediate mode renderer and an offscreen buffer renderer that is multiprocessing enabled.  I use a single task multiprocessing offscreen buffer to render the image, and display it using fig.figimage(_buffer,zorder=100) instead of the immediate mode, if a quiver plot is called for.  3x slower but doesn't leak memory.

Comment: for reference https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2556

Comment: @MarkB does `import gc` and then after `Q.remove()` use `gc.collect()` help?

Comment: I had the gc.collect() code in there at the spot were it might do some good but it didn't improve matters so I removed it for clarity if the example code